# In MonoGame, how can I disable font anti-aliasing?

Tags: xna, monogame, text, antialiasing

I am building a game with a "low resolution" aesthetic, so I would like to disable the default font anti-aliasing. The text is drawn using the built-in SpriteFont and SpriteBatch classes.

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

Here is what I would like it to look like:

[image]

(Please ignore the particles)

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What does the font actually look like? Are you hoping for a way to make a regular font look like the one on the bottom? If you have the text on the bottom as a font and are drawing it without re-sizing it then it should look like the text on the bottom.

Comment: The font is Arial Narrow. The bottom image was done in Photoshop by setting the smoothing to "None".

Comment: @asafafas XNA fonts are simply images. Load the image file in photoshop, set the smoothing to none, then load it up in your content project.See https://web.archive.org/web/20140812180813/http://www.nubik.com/SpriteFont/SpriteFont2Installer.zip.

Comment: Did you set the samplerstate to `SamplerState.PointClamp` in your SpriteBatch.Begin?

Answer (score 4):

To turn off antialiasing, all you have to do is change your sampler state to `SamplerState.PointClamp` in your `spriteBatch.Begin()` call. Here's a short code example:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred,
      BlendState.AlphaBlend,
      SamplerState.PointClamp,
      null, null, null, null));

// Draw text here using DrawString

spriteBatch.End();

spriteBatch.Begin()

// Draw textures, etc

spriteBatch.End()
```

Alternatively to this, you can permanently set the `SamplerState` of the graphics device to `PointClamp` in your `Initialize()` method with the following code (this should work in any method that is only called once, maybe even the constructor):

`graphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointClamp;`

This way, you could use the normal `spriteBatch.Begin()` call with no parameters. Note that this method would apply SamplerState.PointClamp to everything that you draw, not just text

## References:

Here's the reference for XNA's SamplerState, which should be the same as MonoGame's: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.samplerstate_fields%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx

Behind the scenes when actually drawing, SamplerState.PointClamp actually evaluates to:

```
Filter = TextureFilter.Point,

AddressU = TextureAddressMode.Clamp,
AddressV = TextureAddressMode.Clamp,
AddressW = TextureAddressMode.Clamp,
```

(according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.samplerstate.pointclamp%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx))

## Notes:

Another possibility to disable antialiasing would be to change this graphics device setting:

```
Game1.GraphicsDevice.RenderState.MultiSampleAntiAlias = false;
```

Comment: `Filter = TextureFilter.Point` is the key line here. By default, XNA uses a Linear filter, which will interpolate colors when pixels are not one to one. Point filter will, on the other hand, just scale the pixels and do no interpolation.